# MySQL Query Optimization needed

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I'm trying to do a query in mysql

```
   SELECT *
FROM table_name1
WHERE codregister IN
    (SELECT register
     FROM tablename2
     WHERE city LIKE '%paris%')
ORDER BY date DESC
```

In table_name "codregister" is a primary key but in tablename2 "register" field column is a index (primary key on tablename2 is an autoincrement).

In the table_name1 doesn´t have matches with the tablename2 but the execution time of the query is to slow. Someone can recommend to improve the query?

Comment: It's slow because you have nested selections, so if you want to speed it up that would be the first place to look (using `INNER JOIN` or something to the effect).

Comment: time execution dude? I don't know who you're talking about...

Comment: Sorry, I've confused a word with my language. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this considerable difference from csf answer

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    table_a a 

    INNER JOIN 

    (SELECT register 
     FROM table_b 
     WHERE city like '%paris%') b
ON(a.codregister=b.register)
ORDER BY a.date
```

You're only projecting the only field of **B** that you need, and you are filtering **B** records before the **join**.

Comment: Thanks, your reply was useful to me, the execution time is more faster with your query.

Comment: One more question related, Is advisable always filter with a subquery the table that is joined even if the subquery not have like or where clause ?

Answer (score 1):

Use JOIN instead , and make sure joining variables are indexed .

```
SELECT * FROM table_name1 a
JOIN tablename2 b on a.codregister = b.register
where b.city like '%paris%'
ORDER BY a.date  DESC
```

Also for any query you write try to use 'EXPLAIN' to find more about your query 
Ref :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Thanks also for your reply. ;)

Answer (score 0):

i agree with 0R10N Answer , filtering before join can make join faster . ThankI